# Bad Port error on ufw command from Python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, ufw

I'm working on a Python script that has to install some requirements into the computer, and I do it using `subprocess`, like so:

```
firewall_apache = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "ufw", "allow", "\"Apache Full\""], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
for line in iter(firewall_apache.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line)

firewall_apache.communicate()
if firewall_apache.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception
```

It works fine with other requirements, but not with the `ufw`.

If normally executed into the cmd (`sudo ufw allow "Apache Full"`), it works. But when executed from the subprocess, I receive:
`ERROR: Bad Port`.

`sudo ufw app list` result is:

```
Available applications:
  Apache
  Apache Full
  Apache Secure
  CUPS
```

Am I using the wrong subprocess method? What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by simply removing the double quotes inside the last parameter.

```
firewall_apache = subprocess.Popen(["sudo", "ufw", "allow", "Apache Full"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
```

Looks like Python already converts it as a string if it has a blankspace.

Comment: It's actually the other way around. The shell turns your quoted strings into the arguments `argv` that get sent to the binary itself.